# Как добавить свои стили в input?

Tags: css, input, style

Вот сам [фильтр с input](http://panorama.cosmos-team.ru/?page_id=11), никак не могу поменять размеры инпутов, вообще никак

[ссылка на верстку фильтра](http://prntscr.com/c34vai)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как поступить? обычной правкой css файла не обойтись

Comment: Вы можете привести пример, как Вы пытались поправить стиль CSS?

Comment: По крайне мере, можно открыть по FTP стилевой файл css, и отредактировать стили форм.

Comment: да по обычному, немного допер, но не до конца, надо через position:absolute и на label какую-нить картинку засовывать

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете указывать стиль `CSS` для `input` по классу, идентификатору или типу (обычно):

```
input[type="text"], input.someClass, input#someID {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: someValue;
  //И дальше все что вам необходимо
}
```

Есть исключение с инпутами типа `checkbox` и `radio`:
Лучше не использовать `css` с псевдоклассами, потому что будет много проблем в разных браузерах.

Используйте: [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com)